# CodeIgniter where load views

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new in using the CodeIgniter and I want to find the view what contain the page's head, because I want to pleace into that my Google Analytics tracking code. I found my base controller, but in the basic controller I found only this:

```
class Page extends Base_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        // Init the Page TagManager

        TagManager_Page::init();
    }

}
```

Somebody can help me how where can I find that controller and model what loads the view what I want?

Comment: kindly visit http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/toc.html

Comment: Are you sure this is codeigniter?

Comment: go to `application/views/` and find the header there. if there are modules then you need to search them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can load the view using this code..

```
//$this->load->view('viewPageName'); to load file inside application/views/viewPageName


class Page extends Base_Controller
{

  public function index()
  {
    // Init the Page TagManager

    $this->load->view('viewPageName');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want is to template your pages. (you need a php which has header,and another which has footer).

You need to follow the userguide by the makers of codeigniter.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

This above link is how you template it. So in views/templates/header, you can put your analytics.

Answer (score 0):

View is loaded inside the controller function as:

```
$this->load->view("yourviewname");
```

Refer to this link for more details: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Comment: But in the controller I found only the code what I posted above.

Comment: you made this controller or you got from somewhere?

Comment: I only continue the developing of a finished website. What file is executed with that command:

TagManager_Page::init();

Where I need to find the file what contain that command?

Comment: in that case you need to research a lot.we cannot help you by just seeing this much code.may be its calling some template file.you need to check whole project thoroughly.

Comment: I feared from that. :D And can you add some advice how where can I start the finding?

Comment: try to look up in your views folder if there is any template used or your libraries folder if there is any other library file used rhater than CI's inbuilt ones.